# Reproducing performance results for vector insertion with google benchmark

Tags: c++, performance, benchmarking, stdvector, google-benchmark

Recently I saw the following result regarding the insertion of elements into the front of `std::list` and `std::vector`:

- for `std::list` the time is linear
- for `std::vector`the time polynomial
- **but** for a small number of elements (<800) `std::vector` beats list

[image: https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2022/blob/main/Presentations/Refresher-on-Containers-Algorithms-and-Performance.pdf]

src: https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2022/blob/main/Presentations/Refresher-on-Containers-Algorithms-and-Performance.pdf

I tried to reproduce these results with google benchmark.

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

static void bm_vec(benchmark::State &state) {
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        state.PauseTiming();
        std::vector<int> v ;
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(v.data());
        state.ResumeTiming();
        for (int i = 0; i < state.range(0); i++)
        {
           v.insert(v.begin(), 1);
        }
        benchmark::ClobberMemory();
    }
}

BENCHMARK(bm_vec)->DenseRange(10,2000,10);

static void bm_list(benchmark::State &state) {
    
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        state.PauseTiming();
        std::list<int> v ;
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(v.front());
        state.ResumeTiming();
        for (int i = 0; i < state.range(0); i++)
        {
            v.insert(v.begin(), 1);
        }
        
    }
}
BENCHMARK(bm_list)->DenseRange(10,2000,10);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

But my results did not reproduce the desired effect:
[image: very bad results]

Does anyone know what I need to improve to get the desired result?

Comment: Which compile flags are you using? In the presentation, they use -o3. Also, which hardware are you using? They use 8 core CPU.

Comment: Try put `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(v.data());` in inner `for` loop.

Comment: My hardware is: Run on (8 X 4700 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 48 KiB (x4)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x4)
  L2 Unified 1280 KiB (x4)
  L3 Unified 12288 KiB (x1)

Comment: I just saw now that your graph is using nanoseconds (ns) while the original source uses microseconds (us) as reference. If you account for the unit difference, your graph looks like the reference.

Comment: putting `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(v.data());` in the inner for loop did not help. It made the results even less smooth

Comment: Even if you account for the unit difference, the desired behavior (for n < 800 vector faster then list) is not observed

Answer (score 2):

Setting O3( `add_compile_options(-O3)` ) solved the problem.
[image]